# D syntax highlighting in TextMate

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate, d

Hello, guys.

Can I haz syntax hightlighting in TextMate for [D language](http://dlang.org) somehow?

I've searched over the Internets, but haven't found anything. I hope there already exists solution, because it will be sad I will have to create highlighting scheme from scratch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK Sublime Text 2 uses plain TextMate syntax highlighting definitions, so you should be able to use the one that ships with it.

For even better highlighting, there is my patched version of it (shameless plug): https://github.com/alexrp/st2-d